# How can I setup my Django server on LAN

Tags: django, deployment, server, web-deployment, lan

I have made a Django employee portal which will be accessed by LAN only.
It works when another employee opens it by typing the IP address of the server on their web browser.
However I don't have much experience with Django and I think that this is not the proper way to do so. I run my server using python manage.py runserver and use sqlite3 as database.

Is this the correct way to do so? How should I deploy my portal.
I am very new to Django and would appreciate some help.

**I am using a windows machine and I used pycharm to make my project.**

And also I need to know how can I have the server running even when I close pycharm, as ctrl-C or closing pycharm breaks the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Setting up Django and your web server with uWSGI and nginx](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)

There is not an official way to do it, what I do effectively, intranet solutions as well, is with nginx and uWSGI (on ubuntu).

Serving with Windows? perhaps: https://www.toptal.com/django/installing-django-on-iis-a-step-by-step-tutorial is a proper way to do so.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to allow everyone on your network to access your Django webserver is to do `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`
This allows anyone on the network to access it by using your IP address (or computer name) and the port 8000. (so something like 192.168.1.2:8000)

This of course isn't really nice specially if you intent to use this as a production environment. panchicore's answer should help you setup a good production environment.

Comment: not recommended, once the process is killed by some error it won't be up again automatically, instead use supervisor to keep process continuity awareness.

Comment: I didn't say this is the way to go, but it is a quick way to have a test/debug server that can be accessed from different computers on the network

Answer (score 1):

I think for ip address issue you can use host names

https://wesbos.com/localhost-mobile-device-testing/

and for running server in background you can use gunicorn with supervisor check this out https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2014/05/supervisor-with-django-and-gunicorn/