# How can i deploy Django app in a local network

Tags: django, local

I have a local network with 10 computers.

How can i run a django app locally, so that each of the 10 computers can access the app?

Comment: here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51261939/how-can-i-setup-my-django-server-on-lan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, choose a computer to run the Django webserver on.

On this computer, follow the tutorial on [how to run a django webserver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver).

For example: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

`0.0.0.0` exposes your computer's IP address to the network interface. I would also recommend adding `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` to your config file so that django doesn't apply security rules to any visiting IP address. Note: If you have the IP addrs of the devices on your network, you can add them as comma separated strings inside the brackets.

For example `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xxx.xxx.xx.xx', 'xxx.xxx.xx.x']`

You should be able to access the `/` route on your webserver now by typing in the IP address of your host computer followed by `:8000`. For example: `xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8000`.

If your host is running linux you can find its' IP by typing `ifconfig` in the terminal, or on Windows `ipconfig` in your shell of choice.

You can also modify the `/etc/hosts` file to point `yoursite` to `xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8000` and then type in `yoursite` to the browser and it should be able to resolve to your webserver. If you're new to sysadmin-related things though, I would avoid doing this as it can mess up DNS resolution.

Comment: does it make sense to deploy the server via nginx + gunicorn in the local network?

Comment: @AnonymousWizard It depends what you mean by "access". I assume that you are making some kind of internal application for your team/small company. Will it ever touch the (non-LAN) internet? [This article](https://apirobot.me/posts/what-is-wsgi-and-why-do-you-need-gunicorn-and-nginx-in-django) explains it better than I could in a comment why you need the 2.

Comment: @AnonymousWizard I would say yes. The django development server is somewhat limited in functionality. If you want to expand to access the internet some day, Nginx and Gunicorn would be necessary. If you want to grow the app some day, use them. It's also more professional to use them (better error pages, etc.)